# Large gaps between small primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, natural-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

Does there exist a positive integer $n>5$ such that the sum of the two largest primes less than $n$ equals $n$? If yes, lovely! If not, what is the largest prime gap possible between the two largest primes less than $n$?

The first question could also be rewritten as $2*p - n = d$

where $p$ is the largest prime less than $n$ and $d$ is the difference between $p$ and the second largest prime less than $n$.

Comment: Maybe, Bertrand's postulate helps here. It states that for every $n>1$ , $(n,2n]$ contains at least one prime.

Comment: The Wiki page for Bertrand’s postulate mentions a 1952 theorem of Nagura stating that for $n \geq 25$, there is a prime between $n$ and $6n/5$. In particular, for $n \geq 36$, there are two primes between $25/36n$ and $n$, so the sum of the two largest primes less than $n$ is at least $(5/6+25/36-1)n=19n/36 > n/2$.  It’s easy to check what happens with $n<36$. I don’t understand your second question, though.

Comment: There is no limit for the prime gap between the two largest prime numbers less than $n$ because you can make the gap between consecutive primes $p<q$ arbitarily large and just choose $n:=q+1$.

Comment: @Peter I understand that, but I am looking for an 'n' such that the gap between p & q is greater than or equal to n/2.